# Using the movaps operation with a constant value

Tags: c, assembly, opcode

I am attempting to change

```
movaps xmm1,[r9+rax-40]
```

to insert a constant value (23.5 in decimal) into this xmm1 register instead of the contents of the r9+rax-40 address; however, I get that the following is a compile error, where 41BC0000 is the IEEE conversion of 23.5 from decimal to hex:

```
movaps xmm1,41BC0000
```

I'm fairly new to assembly so any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You did not consult the instruction set reference. There is no `movaps` that takes a constant.

Comment: There’s no way to do a move immediate to an xmm register. Usually the value is placed in the rodata section and loaded from there.